# PyCharm подчеркивает красным установленную библиотеку (Django)

Tags: python, django, pycharm

Проблема в том, что PyCharm подчеркивает красным модуль Django, как будто его нет. ПРИ ЭТОМ: проект исправно запускается, а другие модули (к примеру requests или pygame) не подчеркиваются. Пробовал переустановить Django и через pip, и через Python Packages, на пару секунд все хорошо а потом опять. Конечно, можно работать и так, но есть большое желание убрать все это. Прошу помощи

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

в настройках pycharm, вам необходимо указать интерпретатор который у вас в вирутальном окружении, тогда у вас будут видны все пакеты вирутального окружения

Comment: в какие настройки? Project > Python Interpreter? и нужно указать папку venv или какой-то отдельный файл?

Comment: нужно указать папку куда установлен Python

Comment: все верно тебе советуют. в Project > Python Interpreter нужно либо выбрать либо добавить нужное тебе окружение.